# OOP: Composition and public property?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, composition

So lets say I have a class that is composed of other classes.

```
class HttpRequest
{
public $session = new Session();
// .. the rest of the HttpRequest code
}
```

Now, I want to have access to Session class through HttpRequest class so Im using composition.
But does this breaks laws of OOP Encapsulation or Data hidding that states that all properties should be protected, and accessed through setter and getter methods?

Is this wrong:

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->session->set('id', 5);
```

or should I use this:

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$session = $request->getSession();
$session->set('id', 5);
```

Encapsulation states that properties shoud be protected.
How to provide access to inner classes then? Is the first example wrong as far as proper OOP goes?

Comment: You should do neither. Both options violate the Law of Demeter because in each case you're reaching through the request object to get at the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are valid reasons to not allow direct access to the object:

- Allows for manipulation of the object outside of the object itself. If you make the property public, any part of your code could overwrite $session on the HttpRequest class, and you'd have a tough time tracking it down. Encapsulation from a data protection standpoint is there to ensure that only the object's methods can directly alter the object.
- Allows you to gracefully handle the case in which that variable is not set. If, for some reason, $session does not get set on your class - you'll immediately have a fatal when you try to call a method on it. If you wrap it in a getter, you could check for that condition and create a new instance of the class on the fly.
- Follows true "OO" paradigms

However, in some cases I would say it is okay to do this. Particularly if you know that the property will always be set (and the only way in which it would not be set is not a supported way to use the object).

It also makes sense depending on how the property is going to be accessed. Symfony2 uses this in their Request classes. It feels natural in that case, as the "query" "post" and "request" vars are all "ParameterBag"s (glorified arrays). However, they do expose a getter for the Session object - likely because of it's use case.

In short: it really depends on how you'll be using the variable. In this particular case, I'd say it doesn't much matter.

Answer (score 0):

I like your first option, (It's the one using composition),  and look that has encapsulation (I don't know what makes the function set), but I suppose that it's modifying some attribute through the function of the "component" object "session", that pattern is also known as "delegation".

On the other hand if you use encapsulation you cannot user "public", that is allowing to be modified for everybody. It's because of this that you user setters or getter, or in your code "set"

Comment: Yeah, I like the first example better. But im confused with encapsulation since first example looks intuitive to me, and yet it breaks encapsulation. Thats why Im asking this :D Don't know what to do. And yet I want to write OOP code. And Encapsulation is one of four basic OOP rules.

Comment: First: Encapsulation= "private attributes".

If you want to use encapsulation you need to use setters to modify the attribute "id", and another one to modify the attribute what you're modifying assigning the value "5". Both attributes must be privates. Only these both setters can modify those attributes because they are privates.

Comment: So if im using protected then Im not using encapsulation? @itaka

Comment: nono, protected can work as well. The problem with protected is that you limit more the access to your variables (sometimes is a problem, as always depend, the opposite case is with public, you don't limit anything), but usually it's enough with private.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I would use neither of these. Does your HttpRequest object really need to hold onto the Session object or can a Session object be passed into some functions of the HttpRequest object that need it? Is there a strong case for having HttpRequest store this object?